# Firebase asp.net push notifications works locally but not deployed

Tags: asp.net, firebase, notifications, push

I have a 2019 ASP.NET basic project for push notifications using Firebase and swagger and it works locally (i receive the message to my device).  When I publish the project to the local file system and put that on the windows server (iis 10) it does not send the push notification, just reports:
{
"isSuccess": false,
"message": "Something went wrong"
}
What could the problem be?  Is there a way to get a more detailed error?

I uploaded the launchSettings.json with my domain name set in the same folder which is not created when published but that made no difference.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, the error was being handled in the code in a try catch so I just had to show the non-sanitized version of the error.